# Laravel command view not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with laravel. I'm developing a console command just to add it to cron tasks of laravel. But my command for some reason isn't able to find any view. At least to send mails. There it'is de code.

```
<?php foreach ($doctors_notifications_pre['seg3'] as $doctor_id => $doctor_data) {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            $this->registerMailStatus($doctor_data, $seg=3, Mails::PRE);

            Mail::send('emails.prependantSeg3', array('item' => $doctor_data), function($message) {
                $message->from('admin@inventedemail.com')
                        ->to('testing@inventedemail.com')
                        ->subject('Diabet Reseach notification');
            });
            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
    }
```

I've checked the view path, and it seems that it's fine too: resources/views/emails/prependantSeg3.blade.php

So I don't get why laravel can't find the view.

```
xxxxxxx@DESKTOP-O6ATKIT:/mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0$ ./artisan -v crd:sendmails


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  View [emails.prependantSeg1] not found.


Exception trace:
 () at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
 Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:79
 Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php:165
 Illuminate\View\Factory->make() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:441
 Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->getView() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:321
 Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->addContent() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:161
 Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:221
 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/app/Console/Commands/SendMails.php:40
 App\Console\Commands\SendMails->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:794
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /mnt/c/Desarrollo/regueifa1.0/artisan:35
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message you get.

Comment: Oh sorry... forgot it, let me edit the post

Comment: try running these: `php artisan route:clear`,  `php artisan cache:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: If you're running a queue, don't forget to run `php artisan queue:restart` or stop and start your driver.

Comment: Why does it say view `prependantSeg1` not found when you're passing it `prependantSeg3`?

Comment: Cause there's 3m it fails on prependantSeg1 but well after prependantSeg1 it has to do prependantSeg2 and prependantSeg3 sends

Comment: @Advaith tried to do that and same result

Comment: Ok it workes... it seems that laravel console actions works by a little different way than web commands, cause with web commands laravel must generate compiled views or something. Now it was able to find the view and run it fin.